# Register SAS data in metadata using metalib

Tags: sas, metadata

I created a new view in SAS using PROC SQL. Now I'd like to register the view in the metadata in order to enable other users to use the view on a metadata-driven basis.

Using PROC METALIB I'm supposed to be able to do this. I'm required to provide both a library reference (OMR statement) and a dataset reference (SELECT statement). However, the library was already defined when I created the view.

Am I supposed to provide the libref twice or is there a way to register the view with the pre-existing libref that has been provided in the PROC SQL?

If I'm doing this wrong - what would be the correct way to do this using a SAS program?

Example:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE VIEW mylib.myview AS
      SELECT * FROM mytable;
QUIT;

PROC METALIB;
   OMR (library="mylib");
   SELECT ("mylib.myview");
   REPORT;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the full name of the name attribute in metadata. Not just the libref.

If you want to just pass the libref you can use.

```
proc metalib;
  omr (liburi="SASLibrary?@libref='mylib'");
  update_rule=(delete);
     select ("mytable");

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

what I know is that view are not table, which means it works on matadata, alright? Also one more thing, everything that has been entered or created in a session is already kept as and in form of metadata and a view is simply the metadata presented just as table according to the user's requirements. Remember that view works on-the-fly concept of data.like if you created a view in one window then in another window you can simultaneously access that view. So the code you gave in example is correct and you don't need to mention anything twice. Run the code and it should work fine.